# fullcalendar - moved event again restore to old date when click prev/next

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar(v2.0.0) in my application. All events displaying from DB and user can drag and drop and updates events. Everything working fine except that **dropped event again goes to old date when click on fullcalendar's next/prev button**.

check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/3E8nk/1021/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events:"/FullcalendarProject/FullCalendarChecking" 
  // my events will be like this from DB [{title: 'Plants',start: '2015-05-18'}, {title: 'Animals',start: '2015-05-23'}]

});
```

The exact problem is if i drag and dropped **Plants** event to 2015-05-20 then it moved to 2015-05-20 but if i click next/prev then again that moved event go back to 2015-05-18.

Why this happen? How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to write your calendar's drop event callback in which you will send the new date to server and server will update the date of event in db so next time it will come with updated date as follow

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events:"/FullcalendarProject/FullCalendarChecking" ,
  // my events will be like this from DB [{title: 'Plants',start: '2015-05-18'}, {title: 'Animals',start: '2015-05-23'}]
eventDrop: function (event, delta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
                console.log(event);
//asking for confirmation from user using $.prompt you can skip and send direct ajax
                $.prompt("Are you sure you want to move the events "+delta+" days?", {
                    title: "Are you Sure?",
                    buttons: { "Yes": true, "No": false },
                    submit: function (e, v, m, f) {
                        // use e.preventDefault() to prevent closing when needed or return false.
                        // e.preventDefault();
                        if (v)
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/modules/crm_events/support/changeEventDate.php",
                                data: { id: event.id, changeDays: delta , table:event.className[2] , part:event.part },
                                type: "GET",
                                dataType: "json",
                            }).done(function (data) {

                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            revertFunc();
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
});
```

Comment: so page reloading when click on next/prev ?

Comment: no it doesn't reload page when you click on next and prev it sends get request to the specified url in event property of calendar and passes timestamps of start and end date which is currently rendered

Comment: I understood like events function will call everytime when click on prev/next. Am i right?

Comment: correct if its callback then its called if its url then it will go and fetch events.. :)

Comment: same way i am using but i could not get right output check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029194/events-not-display-from-db-in-fullcalendar i hope u can answer for this question